# Android textchange listener

Tags: android

what i want to do is, if text is null then not to call text change listener.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(et1.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                    et1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
                    et1.setText("");
                }
            }
```

This does not work why?

Comment: what does it mean that not work? error? or?

Comment: have you tried `if (et1.toString().equals(""))` ? Or are you getting a nullptr error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editable is declared by the method signature as 's' not 'et1'

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { ... }
```

Comment: OP is probably referencing an `EditText` with the et1 variable as `getText()` is not even a method on an `Editable`

Comment: Ahh I see but the OP probably still wants to look at the size of the     Editable as his reference